# Text disappears on page refresh? (Chrome)

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

I have a html page which links to a php function page, with numerous functions on.
It appears that when the refresh button is clicked in Chrome, the text (only from the functions) disappears. Why would this be caused? This is the same with my update buttons which perform a meta refresh...

```
function Add_Remove_Topics(){
//CONECT TO MYSQL
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "user_test";
$id = ($_SESSION["user_id"]);

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@ mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

//GET VALUES
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

//echo "<div id='add-remove-topics'>";
        //Table headlines - NOT A PHP

        echo "<center>Simply type into the fields to change your current topic information - click update once done editing. If you no longer want one of your topics, click the delete button.</center>";

        echo "<form action='' method='POST'><table id='artopics'>
                <col width='30%'>
                <col width='70%'>
                <col width='70px'>
                <col width='70px'>
                <tr height='40px'>
                    <td style='background-color: #BD4040; color: white; padding-left: 5px;'>Topic Name</td>
                    <td style='background-color: #BD4040; color: white; padding-left: 5px;'>Topic Address</td>
                    <td style='background-color: #BD4040;'></td>
                    <td style='background-color: #BD4040;'></td>
                </tr>";

        // output data of each row

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {


                echo 
                "
                    <tr height='40px'>
                        <td align='center' style='font-weight: normal;background-color: white;'><input type='text' name='up_topic_name[{$row['topic_id']}]' value='" . $row['topic_name'] . "'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='font-weight: normal;background-color: white;'><input type='text' name='up_topic_address[{$row['topic_id']}]' value='" . $row['topic_address'] . "'></td>
                        <td style='background-color: white;' align='center'><button type='submit' name='updateTopic' value='".$row['topic_id']."'>Update</button></td>
                        <td style='background-color: white;' align='center'><button type='submit' name='deleteTopic' value='".$row['topic_id']."'>Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>

                ";



            }

            if(isset($_POST['updateTopic'])){
                $updateID = $_POST['updateTopic'];
                $updateTopicName = $_POST['up_topic_name'][$updateID];
                $updateTopicAddress = $_POST['up_topic_address'][$updateID];
                $updateTopic = mysql_query("UPDATE topics SET topic_name='$updateTopicName', topic_address='$updateTopicAddress' WHERE topic_id='$updateID'") or die(mysql_error());
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
            }


            if(isset($_POST['deleteTopic'])){
                $deleteID = $_POST['deleteTopic'];
                $deleteFromTopics = mysql_query("DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id = $deleteID ") or die(mysql_error());
                $deleteFromUserTopic = mysql_query("DELETE FROM user_topic WHERE topic_id = $deleteID ") or die(mysql_error());
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
            }

        echo "</table></form>";


        echo "<br><center>To add a new topic, simply fill in the fields below, clicking insert once completed.</center>";

        echo "<form action='' method='POST'><table id='artopics'>
                <col width='30%'>
                <col width='70%'>
                <col width='140px'>
                <tr height='40px'>
                    <td style='background-color: #BD4040; color: white; padding-left: 5px;'>Topic Name</td>
                    <td style='background-color: #BD4040; color: white; padding-left: 5px;'>Topic Address</td>
                    <td style='background-color: #BD4040;'></td>
                </tr>";

        // output data of each row



                echo 
                "
                    <tr height='40px'>
                        <td align='center' style='font-weight: normal;background-color: white;'><input type='text' name='new_topic_name'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='font-weight: normal;background-color: white;'><input type='text' name='new_topic_address'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='background-color: white;'><button style='width:130px;' type='submit' name='InsertTopic'>Insert</button></td>
                    </tr>

                ";






            if(isset($_POST['InsertTopic'])){
                $topicName = $_POST['new_topic_name'];
                $topicAddress = $_POST['new_topic_address'];
                $insertIntoTopics = mysql_query("INSERT INTO topics (topic_name, topic_address) VALUES ('$topicName', '$topicAddress') ") or die(mysql_error());
                $grabNewTopicId = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(topic_id) AS topic_id FROM topics") or die(mysql_error());
                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($grabNewTopicId)) {
                    $NewTopicId = $row2['topic_id'];
                    $insertIntoUserTopic = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_topic (user_id, topic_id) VALUES ('$id', '$NewTopicId') ") or die(mysql_error());
                }
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";

            }

        echo "</table></form>";
        }
```

(Screenshots included)

[Before refresh/button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhUB6.png)

[After refresh/button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axamV.png)

Comment: Without code we cant tell you.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the main function. cheers

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the log files (do you have error reporting of level `E_ALL` enabled)?